# Coordinates of bounding box in an image

Tags: opencv, coordinates, object-detection, bounding-box

I am doing object detection in order to count penguins on a UAV georeferenced dataset, so for practical reasons let's say they appear as dots on the images. After running the object detection model, it returns inferred images with the corresponding bounding boxes for each penguin detected.

I need to extract the coordinate of the center of the bounding box (something like x,y), so, as the image is georeferenced, I would be able to convert image b.box center coordinates into GPS coordinates.

This picture is a good example. Here, the authors are counting banana plants, and after detecting the plants of the same regions in 3 differently-treated pictures of the same area, they see that up to three boxes appear around some of the plants (left). So in order to count each plant as one, despite having some of them up to 3 bboxes, this is what they do (quoted from the original article):

1. Collect bounding boxes of detection from each ROI tiles.
2. Calculate centroid of each bounding box.
3. **Add the tile number information on x and y-value of centroids to overlay them on original ROI image.**

[image]

And this is exactly what I am looking for, the step number 3, how to calculate the centroid of each bbox and how to obtain the x,y coords, so then I would be able to transform those coords into real ones, as the image is georeferenced, and then display each real coord on a mosaic.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Value of coord is with reference to which frame?

Comment: I guess it is referenced to the image itself, maybe pixels, I don't really know that, sorry. That was just to give an example. I will edit the questions so it will be easier to understand.

Comment: if you don't really know, nobody else can help. you need to find out what data you have. calculating the center of a box is trivial, if you *have* numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Intersection over Union algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) to select one of the boxes and then use the coordinates of the selected box to plot the output circle or box over detected objects.